# Remove elements and lists in list list in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

So I have this datatype implemented

```
datatype 'a expression = Not of 'a expression
                | Or of 'a expression list
                | And of 'a expression list
                | Equality of 'a expression list
                | Impication of 'a expression * 'a expression
                | Variable of 'a
                | True | False;
```

What I am trying to do is remove whole elements that are the same in the list list. Because i want to follow this mathematical rule and simplify my equation

```
A||(A&&B)∼A
A && (A||B)∼A
```

So what I am looking to do is remove all matches. Meaning my function would remove elements that match like this if the and or statements are correct

```
[[x,y,a], a, [b,c,f],[a,[c,g]]] => [[x,y], a , [b,c,f] [c, g]]
```

And it would also detect and remove whole matching lists like this

```
[[x,y,a], [c, b, d, [x,y,a]] ] => [[x,y,a], [c,b,d]]
```

First it should remove whole matches than it should remove element matches. I kinda came as far as to implement one dimension removal but I am strugling now

```
   fun remove[] = []
  | remove(x::xs) = x::remove(List.filter (fn y => y <> x) xs)
```

Here is what I have and I know it is not even close to the solution

Comment: You can't create those lists in SML to begin with (in a list, all elements have the same type). This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How did you end up wanting to do this?

Comment: You could define your own type of arbitrarily nested lists, of course. (Any problem can be solved by adding a level of indirection.) If this is an exercise, that's probably what you're expected to do.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am aware of this fact. I generalizedmy problem I have a custom datatype made where this is in fact possible. But for simplicity I gave this examples

Comment: Asking about your actual problem instead of an impossible one would save a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you for the heads up was my fault. Updated to match it

Comment: It's not clear at all what the relationship between your expression type and your examples is.